# SQL Constraint: Check that each element in a delimited string is in a list

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a column VARCHAR2(255) I would like to add a constraint that ensures that every element of a delimited string is in a list (no delimiter if only one item):

```
CREATE TABLE fruit (
  fruit_name VARCHAR2(255)
);
ALTER TABLE fruit ADD CONSTRAINT CK_FRT
  CHECK (fruit_name IN ('apple', 'pear', 'peach'));

INSERT INTO fruit VALUES ('apple'); -- Allow this
INSERT INTO fruit VALUES ('apple,peach'); -- Allow this
INSERT INTO fruit VALUES ('peach,apple,pear'); -- Allow this
INSERT INTO fruit VALUES ('dog'); -- DO NOT Allow this
INSERT INTO fruit VALUES ('apple,dog'); -- DO NOT Allow this
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Essentially, I'd love something that worked like python's:

```
all(x in {'apple', 'peach', 'pear'} for x in fruit_name.split(','))
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing that as a comma-delimited list. Just don't do it.

Comment: I agree, but no choice in this instance, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through plenty of docs, I found the `REGEXP_INSTR` function, which solves my problem quite well. So this is what I ended going with:

```
ALTER TABLE fruit ADD CONSTRAINT CK_FRT
CHECK (REGEXP_INSTR(fruit_name, '^((apple|peach|pear),?)+$') > 0);
```

This does allow duplicates and non-delimited splits, but it does ensure that **only** the allowed items are in the string, which is its purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Storing values in delimited lists is highly not recommended.  If you have to do a check like this, then you should really be looking as a junction/association table.

If for some reason you *have* to do this, then you could figure out the regular expression.  I think the easier way is:

```
check (regexp_like(replace(replace(replace(fruit_name, 'apple', ','
                                          ), 'pear', ','
                                  ), 'peach', ','
                          ), '^[,]*$'
                  ))
```

Note that Oracle treats empty strings as `NULL`, which makes this a little more complicated than it needs to be.

EDIT:

Justin is right.  This fixes the problem:

```
check (regexp_like(replace(replace(replace(','||fruit_name||',', ',apple,', ','
                                          ), ',pear,', ','
                                  ), ',peach,', ','
                          ), '^[,]*$'
                  ))
```

Comment: Though that will allow something like `applepear,peachapple,pearpeach`.  That probably isn't a terrible hole (particularly given how poorly done the data model is) but it could be problematic.

Comment: Man I wish there was some syntax like `CHECK (ALL(frt IN ('apple', 'pear', 'peach') WITH frt FROM SPLIT(fruit_name, ',')))`

Comment: @JoshaInglis . . . I for one am rather glad there isn't such syntax. What you are trying to do is store a list in a single string field.  You should be using a separate table for such a list, especially if you have to process each element.

Comment: @JoshaInglis - SQL gives you a data structure *designed* for storing multiple values - it's called a table - so you shouldn't complain too loudly if you decide to mangle multiple values inside of a different data type and then the language doesn't offer convenient facilities to decode what you've chosen to do.

Comment: I understand guys. I would never structure data like this myself. I'm not in a position to alter this, though. So I am left to lament ;)